# saving and restoring registers in an inline assembly code

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

I was writing inline assembly code for an operating system assignment. I have some questions regarding inline assembly and its translation into machine code by the gcc compiler.

1. asm binds input and output to registers. Do we need to save all the registers before doing any operation using asm and restore them back after the operation? Because if the bound register happens to be a register containing an important value in the program, that might be lost and the program might not behave in an expected manner.
2. How is it decided which register will be bound to which input?
3. Does asm save the registers used for input and output and restore
   them on its own?

Edit: Example code is as follows. Which register is top bound to?

    `unsigned long long top;
    asm volatile("mov %0, %%rsp;"
                  :
                  :"r"(top)
                  :"memory");`

Comment: 'asm volatile binds input and output to registers' umm... no.

Comment: 1) Volatile doesn't mean what you seem to think it means. Take a minute to read the gcc [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) about inline asm.  2) If (for some reason) you must bind specific registers to inputs/outputs, look at either the x86 [constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) or [local register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html). There are no guarantees about which registers will get used except for these. 3) If your constraints say you will use a register, gcc makes it available.

Comment: @prl yeah sure. See the edit

Comment: The reason your question was confusing is that you seemed to be focused on ‘volatile’, which is actually not relevant to your question at all. I have edited the question.

Comment: Notes regarding the example code: it is rarely if ever okay to change RSP in inline assembly code. It is rarely if ever okay to change *any* register without telling the compiler you are doing it. It is rarely useful to use inline assembly to do a ‘mov’ instruction.

Comment: @prl But You may need to change RSP in writing os code. One example could be - Suppose you want to implement signal handling. You should invoke the signal handler (if registered through signal syscall) while returning from an interrupt or exception handler. You will need to manipulate user stack and user rip to execute this.

Comment: Atuly, I recommend against doing it in inline assembly. However, I admit that in my current project, there are a couple of places where I do it: in my implementation of longjmp and when switching from 64-bit mode to real mode in order to change the display back to VGA---in other words, highly unusual situations.

Comment: I don't think your example needs to change the current rsp, though, does it? In the situation you describe, aren't you running on the kernel stack at the time that you need to manipulate the user stack?

Comment: @prl yeah, that's the goal. We (Unix in general ) want the signal handler to run in userspace which can be achieved only if we can manipulate user stack from kernel mode. These manipulations are such that it fools the current user program as  if the signal handler was called as a function in userspace

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has a complex register allocation strategy that it uses for inline asm just as it does for code it generates itself. It can use any registers or other locations for the asm parameters that meet the constraints, so it is difficult to predict which registers might be used and it is highly dependent on the surrounding code.

The compiler ensures that other values that are needed by the compiled code are preserved, by putting them in other registers or spilling to memory. The programmer doesn’t have to worry about that.